# Asking to take over permission for message service(SMS) to protect messages from being accessed by other application

Tags: android

Is it possible in android that I create application which will prevent other apps from reading messages such as passwords sent as SMS. And if I see other application accessing message the application will grant access whether to deny or allow another application to read message at runtime. As people install application without seeing the permission it takes. I want to create an app for controlling whether other apps can read message in order to secure password and OTP sent to mobile.
If it's possible please tell how to do it. I am just a beginner android developer

Comment: Better idea-  don't send passwords as an SMS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in android that I create application which will prevent other apps from reading messages such as passwords sent as SMS.

You are welcome to write your own SMS client. On Android 4.4+, your app would be responsible for saving stored messages in the `Sms` and `Mms` providers, and in theory you could do so with some form of encryption.

However:

- You have no means of preventing other apps from seeing SMS messages, as there is no guarantee that you can get in before them
- You would have to write a *full* SMS/MMS client, with the features that users would want, in addition to your desired security
- You need a marketing plan to promote your app, given that every Android user already has an SMS/MMS client

> And if I see other application accessing message the application will grant access whether to deny or allow another application to read message at runtime.

That is not possible, except by your custom version of the operating system.

> I am just a beginner android developer

I suggest that you start with a much simpler project. Or, find an existing open source SMS/MMS client app and work with them to add in your desired feature to that app.

Comment: Thank you that was really useful